# Where is the space leak when using scanl? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

Consider this piece of code:

```
incState state i = map (+ i) state

main =
  sequence_ $ do
    n <- map last $ scanl incState (replicate 1000000 0) (repeat 1)
    return $ print $ n
```

When I run it, memory usage keeps increasing without bounds, as it prints out numbers. Where is the memory leak here? It should only be keeping around a constant amount of memory, previous values of `state` should be discarded whenever it prints something.

Even if `sequence_` or the list monad is holding onto values of `n`, that is only one integer per iteration. I'm seeing 6Gs of memory being used after it only counts up to 100. A million integers should only be taking up 10Ms at most.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is forcing the intermediate calculations through the middle of the list. If you replace `last` with `sum` it stops leaking memory.

To see what's going on, let's consider a slightly simpler statement of the same thing:

```
main = mapM (print . last) $ scanl incState (replicate 5 0) (repeat 1)
```

Now, let's start evaluating it. To begin with, the memory for our state just looks like

```
scanl incState (map (+1) (replicate 5 0)) (repeat 1)
```

We'll skip some of the details, but the first demand we have is that `mapM` pattern matches against the start of the list of states.

```
(:) -> replicate 5 0 
 |     ^
 |     |_________________                     
 v                       |
scanl incState (map (+1) | ) (repeat 1)
```

To get the `last` item to `print`, we force the spine of the list and the last item, but not the individual items. We'll see this better in the next step.

```
       0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : [] 
       ^
       |_________________                     
                         |
scanl incState (map (+1) | ) (repeat 1)
```

For the next step of `mapM`, we need the next item from the list of states. The memory now looks something like

```
       0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : [] 
       ^
       |________                    
                |
(:) -> map (+1) |
 |     ^
 |     |_________________                     
 v                       |
scanl incState (map (+1) | ) (repeat 1)
```

To get the `last` item to `print`, we force the spine of the list and the last item, but not the other individual items.

```
       0   : 0   : 0   : 0   : 0 : [] 
       ^     ^     ^     ^
       |     |     |     |     
       |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : 1 : []
       ^
       |_________________                     
                         |
scanl incState (map (+1) | ) (repeat 1)
```

For the next step of `mapM`, we need the next item from the list of states. The memory now looks something like

```
       0   : 0   : 0   : 0   : 0 : [] 
       ^     ^     ^     ^
       |     |     |     |     
       |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : 1 : []
       ^
       |________                    
                |
(:) -> map (+1) |
 |     ^
 |     |_________________                     
 v                       |
scanl incState (map (+1) | ) (repeat 1)
```

To get the `last` item to `print`, we force the spine of the list and the last item, but not the other individual items.

```
       0   : 0   : 0   : 0   : 0 : [] 
       ^     ^     ^     ^
       |     |     |     |     
       |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : 1 : []
       ^     ^     ^     ^
       |     |     |     |     
       |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : |+1 : 2 : []
       ^
       |_________________                     
                         |
scanl incState (map (+1) | ) (repeat 1)
```

Each time we repeat this, we leave behind another list of thunks, referring to the previous list of thunks, etc. That's where the space leak is coming from. If you force all of the results after each step, like `print . sum` would do, there will not be a space leak.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the Cirdec's answer, to calculate the next state, `incState state i = map (+ i) state` needs the ***previous state*** `state`, and each unforced element in its resulting list will retain a ***reference*** to this previous *state*. So none of those states can be tossed by garbage collection, just in case some other element in addition to `last` might be needed later (even though none ever will, but that's a *whole program* optimization).

To have whole list forced through so the previous list can be forgotten, we can reduce it with `seq`,

```
mapM_ (print . foldl' seq 0) $
   scanl (\s i-> map (+ i) s) (replicate 1000000 0) (repeat 1)
```

Or we can use the transformation

```
map f xs = foldr (\x r-> f x : r) [] xs 
         = foldr (\x r-> let y=f x in y `seq` (y:r)) [] xs
```

to define a "forcing" `map` (I saw this in SO comments few years back, by @luqui, IIRC):

```
mapM_ (print . last) $ 
  scanl (\s i-> foldr (\x r-> let y=(+i) x in y `seq` (y:r)) [] s)
        (replicate 1000000 0) (repeat 1)
```

Of course all this artificially forced superfluous calculations take time, so it's better to change your code, if possible, to not carry around any unnecessary stuff — in effect fusing by hand the `map last` into the `scanl ... replicate ...` *and further into the `incState`* (the step that the compiler couldn't make), to end up with just `mapM_ print $ scanl (+) 0 (repeat 1)`. If possible (on your real case, I mean).